# Youtube dl and Amazon EC2

Tags: youtube-dl, amazon

I have heard of `youtube-dl` for youtube video playlist download.

I want to use trial Amazon EC2 to download youtube videos and transfer them directly to my godaddy ftp account, without having to store these videos on my Amazon account.

How should I proceed?

Comment: The best way to proceed is to browse the documentation and make at least one attempt. What have you tried so far and at which step are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do it is to download the video onto the EC2 machine and then FTP to godaddy. Videos can be of various sizes and can take time to download before they can be FTP. Hence, use cron job that checks that video is downloaded and if so upload to FTP.

AFAIK, there is no package that can do this, so you need to engineer this.

I came across [a NodeJS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-streamer) to upload directly to S3